# Use the IVT to prove that there is a number that exactly 1 more than its 4th root.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I'm unsure as to if this pertains to the previous question which I answered which was this evaluate the following limit by interpreting as a derivative and then using differentiation rules to determine the value of the limit. I'm $\lim_{x\to 2} ((3x^3 - 13x)^3 + 8)/(x-2)$.

Comment: The answer to the question in the body (not the one in the title) is that this question is unrelated to that one. The title is a hint to the proof of the question in the  title.

Comment: Does $x^4-x-1$ take both positive and negative values? If so, then a zero exists by IVT, which however could be negative (and so would not give a solution by raising to the fourth power if only the principal fourth root is allowed).

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang However, if $f(x) = x^4 - x - 1$, then $f(0) < 0$ and $f(2) > 0.$